# How to display products' categories instead of products on search result

Tags: search, magento2.4.2

I'm creating magento 2 store for pre-owned goods.

Even though, in reality, two pre-owned items may be absolutely identical in sense of brand, model, technical specification and so on, I can't display them as the same product with a certain number of items, because of unique physical condition of every item (f.e.: one "Samsung S21 Ultra 12/256" smartphone is in "Good" condition, another one is in "Poor" condition with a lot of scratches on a screen).

So, every such item is displayed as a separate product inside of Category that is named in the name of a product (f.e: category "Mobile phone Samsung S21 Ultra 12/256" contains all "Mobile phone Samsung S21 Ultra 12/256" items).

The problem with this approach appears when you try to search for a certain product (with or without some custom filters applied). If you search for a smartphone with 12 Gb RAM and apply corresponding filter (RAM: 12 Gb) to a search, you'll get in a search result a mess of products with a full content of  "Mobile phone Samsung S21 Ultra 12/256" Category and a full content of every other Category that contains 12 Gb RAM smartphones inside.

The question is: Is it possible to display a list of related categories on search result instead of a list of products. This categories should contain products that are properly filtered by custom filters that customer apply to a product.

F.e.: On search with filters: {"brand": "Samsung"}, {"RAM": "12 Gb"} and {"Item codition": "Poor"}, search result should display "Mobile phone Samsung S21 Ultra 12/256" Category. The category should contain "Mobile phone Samsung S21 Ultra 12/256" items with "Poor" item conditions only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can make attribute options visible on search result page such that users can filter using specific attribute like 'condition'.
Following attribute options settings should be set.

[image]

[image]

**Solution 2**

List out categories as filters in left menu on search result page.

**Solution 3**

Create a custom extension to search and list categories instead of prodcucts.

Comment: Thank you! Solution 2 is an appropriate one.